# Python passing a piped '|' argument in Popen

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to pull data from aws that is base64 encoded. I need to pipe the output through base64 -D to make it readable. When I run the code without the piped base64 argument it returns the output no problem, however, the output is not readable:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
aws_read_report = "aws iam get-credential-report --query 'Content' --output text"
args_read = shlex.split(aws_read_report)
proc_read = subprocess.check_output(args_read)
print proc_read
```

However, when I add the | base64 -D argument as so:

```
aws_read_report = "aws iam get-credential-report --query 'Content' --output text | base64 -D"
```

I get the following error:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
```

To see help text, you can run:

```
  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: base64, -D, |
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cmd_aws.py", line 12, in <module>
    proc_read = subprocess.check_output(args_read)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 574, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['aws', 'iam', 'get-credential-report', '--query', 'Content', '--output', 'text', '|', 'base64', '-D']' returned non-zero exit status 255
```

Also as a side note when I run the command straight from the command line I get the results I want:

```
aws iam get-credential-report --query 'Content' --output text | base64 -D
```

It seems as though the '|' is throwing something off.

Comment: redirection/piping is made by shell/bash so you have to use `shell=True` or you had to use one `suprocess` to get data from `aws` and later second `subprocess` to use `base64` - and you had to manually get data from first `suprocess` and send to second `subprocess`.

Answer (score 3):

To make the pipe work, you need to pass `shell=True` to the `subprocess.check_output()` call: [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Alternatively, you could do your own base64 decoding: https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html

Answer (score 1):

I/O-redirection is a shell feature.  While it's nice and secure to provide a sequence of arguments for execution to subprocess.check_output(), you want something else here.  So don't split your command line and let the shell do what it's supposed to do like:

`proc_read = subprocess.check_output("aws iam get-credential-report --query 'Content' --output text | base64 -D", shell=True)`

Comment: Nice, that gave me the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If it's Linux , at least, I think there are security problems with shell=True.  anyways, here's another link to help you make this work out: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline